# Excel: how to convert text to number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I copied some table with products and prices from a web page to a Excel (2013) worksheet.

Both the source table and my own Excel are configured with French number settings: a thousand euros and 20 cents is formatted `1 000,20 €`

Problem: I cannot get the price column (which contains values from `3 000,00` to `5 000,00`, with no currency unit) to be recognized as numbers by Excel.

I have tried all the solutions(1) mentioned here with no success:
[How to convert text to numbers in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291047) ...

(1)  except writing a VBA script and retyping the values.
Solutions based on "clicking an error message" are not applicable as there is no error message even after setting the `Number` type on the cells.

Is there a solution here ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an efficient solution by pure chance: paste the HTML into a text editor, then copy-paste the raw text into Excel
-- > all numbers were automatically recognized.

Using Excel `Paste Special` function and pasting the HTML as text also works.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had the pastespecial>multiply and paste in a 1 work fine for me.

Perhaps it isn't recognizing the "," properly.  Do a search replace of commas and maybe blanks in the column, see if that helps.  If not try multiplying in the 1 again.

Comment: I have tried replacing the whitespaces with ctrl-H but Excel  did not find any. Certainly because of the HTML nature of the pasted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and could have in 2015) use the function `NUMBERVALUE`.

It takes three parameters:

1. The cell/range/etc. in which the data to convert is.
2. The separator used for decimal separation.
3. The separator used for grouping the integer portion.

No problem for 1 & 2. For the grouping separator, you could, of course, learn what the "white space" character is, but in fact, you can just edit a cell of the data and copy the character to the clipboard. Then paste it into place in the formula. No muss, no fuss.

One caveat:  it will only use a single character for 2 & 3. So if that white space is more than one character, you'd have to rectify that. `Find and Replace` the copied white space with some simple character that is NOT also the shown decimal character, then use that character in the function.

After setting up the formulas to do this to your range of data, then copy the column to the clipboard and paste|special the data over top the source data.

You can add a "helper" column to do it, then delete the column after pasting over the source data, or just insert a sheet and do the work there, then delete it or keep it for future use.

The key is that `NUMBERVALUE` is the easy way to address it in a way that does not depend upon the user's knowledge level or willingness to do the work. For instance, if adding a permanent sheet to do the conversion, your follow-on formulas can refer to IT rather than the actual data.

Additionally, a macro that simply looks to such a sheet for something to copy and pastes the values overtop another existing place is very easy to write vs. one that does the conversion itself. That could allow you to simply place a button that triggers the macro for users to press after data is imported. Might like that yourself if you are the only user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).